# In rails, query by two colums added together?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I want to query by two columns added together like so, but I can seem to get it right:

Let's say the database has two columns: a and b. I would like to query the coumns where a plus b is greater than 100.

```
SomeModel.select("(a + b) as c").where("c > ?", 100)
```

How would you go about doing that? This is in postgres.

I could just loop over each found column and add them together in rain but that seems inefficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This won't help if you're trying to limit the number of columns returned, and it won't help to add a `some_model.c` method, but try this if that's okay:

```
SomeModel.where("(a + b) > ?", 100)
```